# How to detect if an object is made up primarily of stack or dynamic memory

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory

I've currently been working with a library that potentially creates heavy weight objects. Specifically, I'm creating objects that are associated with wave files.

Now when creating an instance of a Wave Object (just as an example), is there a good way to determine where it is being allocated in memory?

For example, if I were to instantiate a std::vector in the stack, I know that some memory is allocated on the stack (i.e. header information) and the actual container data is created on the heap. So for the most part, I don't have to worry about a stack memory overflow. Although I still have the option to fully instantiate the object in heap.

But let's say I don't know about an objects implementation. Let's say I'm using a library that creates a massive array in the stack. This could potentially cause problems.

So my question: how do we know how 'heavy' an object is memory wise?

Comment: The short answer is: you can't. At least not unless you use a factory parttern, that always instantiates your objects on the heap. In which case the answer is always "the heap", of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that extra-standard methods of allocating stack memory are off the table (`alloca` and friends).

Given that, it's simple: take the `sizeof` the object.

C++ is a statically typed language, but its objects are also statically *sized*. Every type has a size that must be determinable at compile-time. Lots of C++ relies on this. So if you're concerned about some object taking up too much stack space, that could only be because the `sizeof` the object took up that space.

Note that this will not prevent issues where you call a function that *itself* uses lots of stack space. There's nothing you can do to detect that. But you can tell if the size of a given object will be "large" or not, by some arbitrary measurement.

Comment: I see. For some reason I was thinking that you could have an object with a member std::array whose size could vary based on the objects constructor call... But the size of the array would have to be fixed and couldn't vary.